# FluentNhibernate and References

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I was trying to change a convention so that my IDs follow this simple rule: **ProductCode**, **CustomerCode**, **OrderCode** etc etc.
I've found a simple way to do that adding a convention:

```
public class PrimaryKeyNameConvention : IIdConvention
        {
            public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IIdentityInstance instance)
            {
                instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Code");
            }
        }
```

Now I've got what I wanted but it seems that FluentNhibernate refuses to apply the same rule with column referencing my primary keys.
EX: my table **Customer** will have a PK called **CustomerCode** but my table **Order** will have a reference column called **Customer_Id**.
I've tried different ways to rename the column **Customer_Id** in **CustomerCode** (table **Order**) but it seems that nothing works properly.
The only solution which seems to work is adding a convention like this:

```
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention
        {
            public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IManyToOneInstance instance)
            {
                instance.Column(instance.Property.PropertyType.Name + "Code");
            }
        }
```

but now FluentNhibernate creates two columns which reference my primary key: **CostumerCode** and **Customer_Id**.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be apreciated.

Regards,

Alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [ForeignKeyConvention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions#ForeignKeyConvention) base-class.

> The ForeignKeyConvention is an amalgamation of several other conventions to provide an easy way to specify the naming scheme for all foreign-keys in your domain. This is particularly useful because not all the foreign-keys are accessible in the same way, depending on where they are; this convention negates need to know about the underlying structure.

Comment: Thanks James,

it worked.
I've applied these two conventions and it worked as expected:

PrimaryKeyNameConvention + ForeignKeyConvention

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

As James suggested I've now applied these two conventions:

```
public class PrimaryKeyNameConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Code");
    }
}

public class CustomForeignKeyConvention : ForeignKeyConvention
{
    protected override string GetKeyName(Member property, Type type)
    {
        if (property == null)
            return (type.Name + "Code");    // many-to-many, one-to-many, join

        return (property.Name + "Code");    // many-to-one
    }
}
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: Good to hear. If you wanted a single convention, there's nothing to stop you implementing `IIdConvention` in your `CustomForeignKeyConvention` class instead of on it's own.